# Transaction vs Batch Query to Avoid Duplicate MySQL Inserts

Tags: php, mysql, sql, locking, race-condition

I have a `PHP` script (`deleteAndReInsert.php`) that deletes all rows where `name = 'Bob'`, and then inserts 1000 new rows with `name = 'Bob'`. This works correctly, and the initially empty table ends up with 1000 total rows as expected.

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM table WHERE name=?");
$query->execute(['Bob']);

$query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO table (name, age) VALUES (?,?)");
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++)
{
    $query->execute([ 'name' => 'Bob', 'age' => 34 ]);
}
```

The problem is if I run `deleteAndReInsert.php` twice (almost at the exact same time), The final table contains more than 1000 rows.

What seems to be happening is that the `DELETE` query from the first run finishes, and then many (but not all) of the `1000 INSERTS` get called.

Then the second `DELETE` query starts and finishes before the first 1000 `INSERTS` finishes (say 350 of the 1000 `INSERTS` complete). Now the second 1000 `INSERTS` runs, and we end up with 1650 total rows instead of 1000 total rows because there are still `1000 - 350 = 650 INSERTS` remaining after the second `DELETE` gets called.

What's the correct way to prevent this problem from happening? Should I wrap everything in a transaction, or should I make 1 batch insert call instead of 1000 individual inserts? Obviously I can implement both of these solutions, but I'm curious as to which one is guaranteed to prevent this problem.

Comment: A transaction probably won’t help you because you have multiple inserts and there’s no real way to say which is right or wrong. Instead, I would look into application-level locks, which could be done manually, or through a component such as [symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/lock.html). When your scripts starts, it should lock itself from additional runs until it is complete.

Comment: You _could_ lock the whole table before writing to it... A transaction would not help, as this only isolates the operations, but doesn't prevent others from accessing the table.

Comment: What's the `PRIMARY KEY` on the table?  For completeness, please provide`SHOW CREATE TABLE table`.

Comment: What is the problem??  Sure the 1650 count is wrong, but the table is not wrong.  You end up with exactly 1000 rows.  You have not mentioned whether a _second connection_ is involved.  If that is part of the question, you must say how it is involved.

Comment: @RickJames there's no `PRIMARY KEY`, and there is a second connection. I open deleteAndReInsert.php in two different browser windows at almost the exact same time.

Comment: @DavidMarcus -- Then you need `BEGIN...COMMIT` around the code.

Comment: @DavidMarcus - Please move that information in the body of the Question.  Else, the Answers are having to guess why there could be a problem.

Comment: execute a [write lock](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html) prior the delete operation, and `UNLOCK TABLES` once you have completed the inserts.

Comment: I notice you are not checking for errors after the calls to `prepare()` and `execute()`. Would you consider doing that? Or else enabling PDO exceptions. It would be useful to know why some inserts are failing, and which ones.

Comment: @BillKarwin the code runs without exceptions. The problem is that if you run the script twice at the same time, the queries get called twice and you end up with duplicates in the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Using transactions + batch insert

I think that the correct way to solve the problem is using transaction. We are going to do a Delete + a batch insert, here is the code:

```php
$pdo->beginTransaction();
$query = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM table WHERE name=?");
$query->execute(['Bob']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO table (name, age) VALUES ".implode(', ',array_fill(0,999, '(:name, :age)'));
$query = $sth->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array([ ':name' => 'Bob', 'age' => 34 ]));

$pdo->commit();
```

## Using just a batch insert (Won't work)

Why to do just a batch insert not solves the problem? Imagine the follow scenario:

1. First script make a delete and remove the first 1000 rows. ==> Form 1000 rows to 0.
2. Second script try to make a delete but there are no rows.  ==> Form 0 rows to 0.
3. First (or second) script make a 1000 batch insert. ==> Form 1000 rows to 1000.
4. Second (or first) script make a the second 1000 batch insert. ==> Form 1000 rows to 2000.

This is why the process are asynchronous, so the second script may read the table befores the first script finish the insert.

## Using a secondary table to simulate a lock (Not recomended)

And if we don't have transaction, how we would solve that problem? I think that is is an intersecting exercise.

This is a classic concurrency problem where there are two or more process modifying same data. To solve that problem, I propose  you use a second auxiliary table for simulate a [Lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)) and control the concurrency access to the main table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `access_table` (
  `access` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
)
```

And in the script

```php
// Here we control the concurrency
do{
   $query = $st->prepare('UPDATE access_table SET access = 0 WHERE access = 1');
   $query ->execute();
   $count = $query ->rowCount();
   // You should put here a random sleep
}while($count === 0);


//Here we know that only us we are modifying the table
$query = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM table WHERE name=?");
$query->execute(['Bob']);

$query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO table (name, age) VALUES (?,?)");
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++)
{
    $query->execute([ 'name' => 'Bob', 'age' => 34 ]);
}


//And finally we open the table for other process
$query = $st->prepare('UPDATE access_table SET access = 1 WHERE access = 0');
$query ->execute();
```

You can adapt the table to your problem, for example, if the  INSERTS/DELETES are by name, you can use a `varchar(XX)` for name.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `access_table` (
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `access` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
)
```

With this scenario

1. First script change the access value to 0.
2. Second script can't change the value so it stay in the loop
3. First script makes the DELETES/INSERTS
4. First script change the status to 1
5. Second script changes the access value to 0 and breaks the look.
6. Second script makes the DELETES/INSERTS
7. Second script change the status to 1

This is because updates are atomics, that means that two process cannot update the same date at same time, so when the first script update the value, the second script can not modify, that action is atomic.

I hope to have helped you.

Comment: If, by "batch insert", you mean a single `INSERT` with 1000 rows, well that is atomic regardless of what locking mechanism is used.  Please be clear about your meaning of "batch insert".

Comment: This is the correct answer (use a transaction), but there's an error in the code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

you have to lock the operation and dont release it before insertion ends.

you can use a file on filesystem, but as @chris Hass suggested you can use symfony's package like this:

install symfony lock:

```
composer require symfony/lock
```

you sould include composer's autoload

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
```

then in your deleteAndReInsert.php :

```php
use Symfony\Component\Lock\LockFactory;
use Symfony\Component\Lock\Store\SemaphoreStore;

//if you are on windows or for any reason this store(FlockStore) didnt work
// you can use another stores available here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/lock.html#available-stores 
$store = new FlockStore();
$factory = new LockFactory($store);
$lock = $factory->createLock('bob-recreation');
$lock->acquire(true)

$query = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM table WHERE name=?");
$query->execute(['Bob']);

$query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO table (name, age) VALUES (?,?)");
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++)
{
    $query->execute([ 'name' => 'Bob', 'age' => 34 ]);
}
$lock->release();
```

### What Happened

as you mentioned what happened is a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#In_software):

> If Two Concurrent process are accessing a **Shared Resource**,
> That resembles the **Critical Section** Which maybe needs to get protected with locks

Comment: Would it make more sense to lock the database table instead of the php file?

Comment: And what happens if the second script is not made in PHP? And if is it in other computer? I think to control the database access concurrency using code is not a good idea.

Comment: What SQL does `LockFactory` use under the covers?

Comment: @david Marcus : database has locks in two levels: row level & table level based on the engine you use (InnoDB or MyIsam). but before any query execution DB get locked and get released after each query execution to ensure that nothing can be writen into one row while it is writing. but here there are 1001+1001 independent queries are executing.

Comment: @DavidMarcus but we can use a lock mechanism via DB, the symfony has DB lock factory, which can be used instead of file. it create a table and put a row as the lock in that table, and while the row exists, it doesnt write anything else using he above code

Comment: @Pericodes This is the [famous CS reader-writer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem) which exists when two writer wants to write to a share resource, it doesnt need to be DB, it could be a shared network medium, a shared file on the system, ... . the solution to this problem is to use locks (there are variety of them like shared lock ...). and there are multiple implementations like synchronous locks and Asynchronous Locks.

Comment: @Pericodes here we have used **Synchronous Lock** `$lock->acquire(true)` and it make another thread waiting while this process hasnt finished its job, and released the lock

Comment: @RickJames its just [create a lock based on the Store](https://github.com/symfony/lock/blob/3276c00b36e0da96dae794e1317783113d5d4d08/LockFactory.php#L44)

Comment: @RickJames and store is the strategy to conducting lock

Comment: @DavidMarcus please see the example on the wikipedia, which I have provided a link to it.

Comment: @Abilogos I saw the link, and I think you're right that this is the problem I'm facing.

Comment: @DavidMarcus you are welcome, if you have any question, please don't hesitate to ask

Comment: @davidMarcus : has my answer helped you? is it acceptable?

Comment: @Abilogos your answer works, but the simplest answer is to user a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the other solutions is to create an actual lock file when the script launches and check if it exists before running.

```
while( file_exists("isrunning.lock") ){
    sleep(1);
}

//create file isrunning.lock
$myfile = fopen("isrunning.lock", "w");

//deleteAndinsert code

//delete lock file when finished
fclose($myfile);
unlink("isrunning.lock");
```

Comment: PHP actually has built-in functions for obtaining file locks (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php). Rolling your own solution is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

**The count is an approximation**

`SHOW TABLE STATUS` (and many variants on such) provide only an estimate of the number of rows.  (Please say how you are getting the "1650".)

The precise way to count is

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table;
```

---

**Further discussion**

There are 2 main ways to do "transaction locking".  Both protect against *other* connections interfering.

- Autocommit:

  ```
  SET autocommit = ON;   -- probably this is the default
  -- Now each SQL statement is a separate "transaction"
  ```
- BEGIN...COMMIT

  ```
  BEGIN;  -- (this is performed in a variety of ways by the db layer)
  delete...
  insert...
  COMMIT;  --everything above either entire happens or is entirely ROLLBACK'd
  ```

**Performance:**

- `DELETE` --> `TRUNCATE`
- Batched insert (1000 rows in a single `INSERT`)
- `BEGIN...COMMIT`
- `LOAD DATA` instead of `INSERT`

But *none* of the performance techniques will change the problem you are encountering -- except "coincidentally".

---

**Why 1650?**

(or some other number)  InnoDB's transactional nature requires that it hang onto previous copies of rows that are being deleted or inserted until the `COMMIT` (whether explicit or autocommit'd).  This clutters the database with "rows" that might go away.  Hence any attempt to dead-reckon the exact number of rows is not practical.

That leads to using a different technique to *estimate* the row count.  It goes something like this:  The table takes this much disk, and we have an estimate that the average row is this many bytes.  Divide those to get the row count.

That leads to your theory about the Delete not being finished.  As far as any SQL goes, the Delete *is* finished.  However the temporarily saved copies of the 1000 rows have not been thoroughly cleaned out of the table.  Hence, the imprecise computation of the number of rows.

---

**Locking?**

*No* locking technique will "fix" the 1650.  Locking is needed if you don't want other threads inserting/deleting rows while running your Delete+Insert experiment.  You should use locking for that purpose.

Meanwhile, you *must* use `COUNT(*)` if you want the precise count.

Comment: I am using COUNT(*), so the 1650 number is exact.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the correct way to prevent this problem from happening?

This is not a problem and is expected behaviour for two pages accessing the same table on a database.

> Should I wrap everything in a transaction, or should I make 1 batch insert call instead of 1000 individual inserts? Obviously I can implement both of these solutions, but I'm curious as to which one is guaranteed to prevent this problem.

Won't make a blind bit of difference other than limiting the amount of inserts to be n000 by the number of pages you run.

---

Scenario 1 - do nothing

There are two pages running one after the other or at similar times. This is why you are seeing 1650 records due to implicit transactions within the execute method, allowing other processes (pages in your case) to access the data in a table.

| Action | Page a | Page b | Table Row count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Deletes all Bobs |  | 0 |
| ... | Insert a row |  | 1 |
| 351 | Insert a row | Deletes all Bobs | 0 |
| 352 | Insert a row | Insert a row | 2 |
| ... | Insert a row | Insert a row | 4 |
| 1001 | Insert a row | Insert a row | 1298 |
| 1002 |  | Insert a row | 1299 |
| ... |  | Insert a row | ... |
| 1352 |  | Insert a row | 1650 |

Thus 1650 Bobs are inserted.

---

Scenario 2 - use explicit transactions (optimistic)
| Action | Page a | Page b | Table Row count | Transactions |
| ----- | ------ | ------ | --- | --- |
| 1 | starts |  | 0 | |
| 2 | Deletes all Bobs | starts | 0 | (a-d0)|
| 3 | Inserts 1000 rows | Deletes all Bobs | 0| (a-d0-i1000)(b-d1000)  |
| 4 | commits | Inserts 1000 rows | 1000 | (b-d1000-i1000) |
| 5 |  | commits | 1000 |

---

Scenario 3 - add locking
| Action | Page a | Page b | Table Row count |
| ----- | ------ | ------ | --- |
| 1 | AQ lock |  | 0 |
| 2 | starts |  | 0 |
| 3 | Deletes all Bobs | AQ lock | 0 |
| 4 | Inserts 1000 rows | no lock| 0|
| 5 | commits | no lock | 1000 |
| 6 | | AQ lock | 1000 |
| 6 | | starts  | 1000 |
| 6 | | Deletes all Bobs | 1000 (0) |
| 6 | | Inserts 1000 rows | 1000 (1000) |
| 6 | | unlock | 1000 |

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Process List on the Server and prevent your script from executing, if there is another instance.

Answer (score 0):

you hit `deleteAndReInsert.php` twice, and each of script has 1001 commands, first is delete all `name = Bob` and the rest is insert 1000 times Bob again.
so totally you have 2002 commands, and the you don't declare somethings that make Mysql understand that you want to execute it synchronous, and your 2002 commands will run concurrent, and will lead to the unexpected result. (more than 1000 inserted `name= Bob`). the process could described like this:

```
->delete `name= bob` (clear count = 0)
->insert `name = bob`
->insert `name = bob`
->insert `name = bob`
->insert `name = bob`
....
->insert `name = bob`
->delete `name= bob` (the second time deleteAndReInsert.php 
hit deleted at 300 times insert `name = bob` of first
 time deleteAndReInsert.php -> clear count rows = 0)
->insert `name = bob`
->insert `name = bob`
->insert `name = bob`
....
-> insert `name = bob` (now it could be more than 1000 rows)
```

So if you want the result is 1000 rows. you must make mysql understand that: i want deleteAndReInsert.php that run synchronous, step by step. and to archived that you can do one of these solutions:

1. use `LOCK TABLE` statement to lock table and `UNLOCK` when finish, that make second script can not do anything with table unless the first script is done.
2. wrap all in transaction `BEGIN COMMIT` then mysql will run as an atomic action. (Good)
3. simulate `LOCK` by redis (Redlock), file .. to make your action run synchronous (Good)

Hope that could help you solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is issuing a `LOCK TABLE ... WRITE` as the first statement of your job, and `RELEASE TABLES` as its last.

Then the thousand rows will be deleted, then inserted, then deleted, then inserted again.

But the whole procedure smells like a XY problem to me. What is it that you *really* need to do?

Because I have often needed to do something like this that you describe ("refreshing" some summaries for example), and the best way to do this is, in that scenario and in my opinion, *neither* LOCK *nor* DELETE/INSERT, but rather

```
INSERT INTO table
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
```

In my case, if I only need to *add* or *refresh* records, that is enough.

Otherwise, I usually add a "time" field that allows me to recognize all the records that were "left out" from the refresh cycle; those - and only those - get deleted upon finish.

For example, say that I need to calculate, with a complex PHP calculation, the maximum financial exposure for many customers, and then insert into a table for ease of use. Each night every customer has its values refreshed, then the next day the "cache" table is used. Truncating the table and reinserting everything is a pain.

Instead, I calculate all values and build a very large multiple INSERT query (I could split it into X smaller multiple queries if needed):

```
SELECT barrier:=NOW();
INSERT INTO `financial_exposures` ( ..., amount, customer_id, last_update )
    VALUES 
    ( ..., 172035.12, 12345, NOW()),
    ( ..., 123456.78, 12346, NOW()),
    ...
    ( ..., 450111.00, 99999, NOW())
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
         amount=VALUES(amount),
         last_update=VALUES(last_update);
 DELETE FROM financial_exposures WHERE last_update < @barrier;
```

New customers get inserted, old customers get updated unless their values are unchanged (in that case MySQL skips the update, saving time), and at each instant, a record is always present - the one before the update, or the one after the update. Removed customers get removed as the last step.

This works better when you have a table that you need to frequently use *and* update. You can add a transaction (`SET autocommit = 0` before the `INSERT`, `COMMIT WORK` after the `DELETE`) with no locks to ensure that all clients see the whole update as if it happened instantly.

Comment: this is an interesting technique, but it relies on there being unique database constraints. I think a solution like this is best for most real life problems. The problem in the question is a little trickier because there are no database constraints, and it wouldn't make sense to add one.

Answer (score 0):

@Pericodes' answer is correct, but there's an error in the code snippet.

You can avoid duplicates by wrapping the code in a transaction (batch insert isn't required to stop duplicates).

It's better to use 1 batch insert instead of 1000 separate inserts even though it's not required.

You can test by running this code twice (almost at the same time), and the table ends up with exactly 1000 records.

```
<?
$pdo->beginTransaction();

$query = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM t1 WHERE name=?");
$query->execute(['Bob']);

$query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO t1 (name, age) VALUES (:name,:age)");
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++)
{
    $query->execute([ 'name' => 'Bob', 'age' => 34 ]);
}

$pdo->commit();
```

Several of the answers mention locks (db-level and code-level), but those aren't necessary for this problem, and are overkill imo.